# Как вывести в переменную текст из QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qplaintextedit

Подскажите как можно вывести текст в переменную при данной конструкции:

```
...  
   
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 40, 341, 41))
    self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.textEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
    self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

  class ShowPath(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
    
def getFileName(self):
            filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
            self.textEdit.clear()
            path = self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename, filetype))
    
            print(path)


...
```

в консоль выводит

> None

Comment: Аполлинарий Кодоправ, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и лучше объясните зачем вам, какой-то `path`, если  вы определяете путь к файлу в переменную `filename`?

Comment: @S.Nick Спасибо, поставе в ответ, я не так давно python могу задавать очень глупые вопросы.

Comment: Аполлинарий Кодоправ, пожалуйста. Вы видимо хотите прочитать `Excel` и показать его в какой-то таблице. Если так, то на эту тему есть много вопросов, почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+Excel и никогда не забывайте публиуовать минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @S.Nick да всё верно хочу сравнить 3 excel файла и результат анализа вывести в 4 й файл excel, спасибо за ссылку,  возможно скоро начнутся вопросы по pandas )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод appendHtml выполняет действие, но не возвращает никакого значения.

Поэтому нет никакого смысла делать такое:

```
path = self.textEdit.appendHtml("что-нибудь")
```

т.к. результат всегда будет None.

Насколько я могу судить по документации (сам с Qt не работал, так что могу ошибаться), вам нужно заменить это:

```
path = self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename, filetype))
```

На такое:

```
self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(filename, filetype))
path = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
```